# App Crash in GMSPlace Picker while running on device.(iOS 8.3)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsplace

I'm using following code to pick location as suggested by Google

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker

```
    var placePicker: GMSPlacePicker?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.pickPlace()
    }

  func pickPlace()
    {
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5108396, -0.0922251)
        let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001)
        let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001)
        let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
        let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
        placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

        placePicker?.pickPlaceWithCallback({ (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error
            {
                print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let place = place
            {
                print("Place name \(place.name)")
                print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)


            } else
            {
                print("No place selected")
            }
        })
    }
```

[image]
Issue with this code is its running perfectly on simulator but on device iOS 8.3 it crashes without giving any message

Comment: Did you enable zombie object? It can give you more detail

Comment: yes i did Product->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics-> Click Enable Zombie Objects. But does not affects anything.:(

Comment: Did you give permission for your app to get location, or did u set location service on in your real device? Can you set breakpoint on your code to see where it crash?

Comment: Yes i did permission always. it crashes on AppDelegate.

Comment: Sorry for stupid solution, but can you delete your app, restart your phone and build again :)), I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Change NSError to Error

```
placePicker?.pickPlaceWithCallback({ (place: GMSPlace?, error: Error?)
```

Import these both in AppDelegate class

```
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
```

And, you need to set these both in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("Your key")
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("Your key")

        return true
    }
```

I couldn't see the error message using device, only after i tested it in the simulator